# How to edit sites from Google Chrome on Android that are appearing when typing URL?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

How to edit sites that are highlighted in this image:

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Just top on this icon, then you can able to edit. This is the only solution :)

[image: Edit info]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use red color round circle pencil control for editing.
You can also use Right Arrow sign for edit.